# Why can you not get the borel set by taking countable unions, intersections, and complements?

Tags: general-topology

Given a subset $S$ of the powerset of $R$, define the following operations on it:

$f(S)=$ All countable unions of elements in $S$.
$g(S)=$ The union of $S$ and complements of sets in $S$.

Say we start with the set of all open sets, $U$.

Can we reach the Borel set by applying finitely many $f,g$?

Comment: Wikipedia seems to indicate that you need countably many such operations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set

Comment: @OlivierMoschetta thanks, looking for a proof as well :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP asks (clarified in the comments below this answer): "Is there a finite $n$ such that the sets constructed in $n$ steps from open sets via countable union and complementation, are exactly the Borel sets?"

The answer is no, (see pages 23-24 of [these notes](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~marker/math512/dst.pdf) (but beware of typos!), or Theorem 22.4 in Kechris' book [Classical Descriptive Set Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387943749)).

The meat of the proof is the construction of *universal sets*. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be Cantor space with the usual topology, and write $\Sigma^0_n(X)$ (etc.) for the class of subsets of $X$ which are $\Sigma^0_n$ in the sense of $X$ (etc.). Fix $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $X$ a Polish space; then a set $U\subseteq \mathcal{C}\times X$ is **$\Sigma^0_n$-universal** if $U$ is $\Sigma^0_n(\mathcal{C}\times X)$ and for all $\Sigma^0_n(X)$ $V$ we have $$V=\{x: (c, x)\in U\}$$ for some $c$; $\Pi^0_n$ universality is defined analogously.

Intuitively, a $\Gamma$-universal set is a $\Gamma$-set which contains every $\Gamma$-set as a "row"; if you know some computability theory, think about how the complete c.e. set has every c.e. set "coded" into it appropriately (this analogy can in fact be made precise and proved).

The existence of universal sets (for any Polish space $X$!) is not at all obvious, and is proved by induction on $n$. Rather than post it here, I'll direct you to the sources above, since it's somewhat messy.

Now, suppose we have a $\Sigma^0_n$-universal set $U\subseteq\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{C}$. Then if we take $Y=\{x: (x, x)\not\in U\}$, $Y$ is a $\Pi^0_n$ set, but $Y$ can't be $\Sigma^0_n$: otherwise by universality of $U$ there would be an $x\in X$ such that $y\in Y$ iff $(x, y)\in U$, but then $$x\in Y\iff (x, x)\in U\iff x\not\in Y.$$
Now, since every $\Pi^0_n$ set is $\Sigma^0_{n+1}$, this means that the Borel hierarchy doesn't stop after finitely many levels . . .

. . . on Cantor space, that is! What about $\mathbb{R}$? Well, here we run into the fact that, basically, all the Polish spaces (other than $\mathbb{N}$ and its variants) have the same Borel structure. If $X$ is an uncountable Polish space, $X$ contains a perfect $P\subseteq X$ which is homeomorphic to $\mathcal{C}$, and we can run the above argument on that perfect set.

---

What about if we weaken the requirement a little - does every *specific* Borel set arise after finitely many stages?

No, finitely many steps are not enough - you need to continue through the countable ordinals (so each *specific* Borel set can be built in countably many stages, but to build them *all* we in fact need uncountably many stages).

Why? Well, here's a rough explanation. Let $\Sigma^0_1$ be the class of open sets, $\Pi^0_n$ be the class of complements of $\Sigma^0_n$ sets, and $\Sigma^0_{n+1}$ be the class of countable unions of $\Pi^0_n$ sets. Then the class $$\Sigma^0_\omega=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \Sigma^0_n$$ is the collection of all Borel sets built in finitely many "steps".

Now for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $X_n\subseteq (n, n+1)$ be $\Sigma^0_{n+1}$ but not $\Sigma^0_n$. (The existence of such $X_n$ is a good exercise.) Then $$Y=\bigcup X_n$$ is a Borel set, being the union of countably many Borel sets; but $Y$ can't be $\Sigma^0_n$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Why can't $Y$ be $\Sigma^0_n$? Well, suppose it were. Then look at $Y\cap (n, n+1)$. As the intersection of an open set and a $\Sigma^0_n$ set, this is $\Sigma^0_n$ (this is a good exercise - induction on $n$); but $Y\cap (n, n+1)=X_n$ is *not* $\Sigma^0_n$.

Comment: I mean this is a good answer, but you're just taking my question and saying this is a good execrise. I asked about finitely many times applying f,g, and you're solving the using countably many f,g case, using the finite case (my question). In fact I'm not sure why you don't conclude the countable case but the finite case, which you use in your proof.

Comment: Sorry your argument doesn't show the countable case, it's just circular.

Comment: @Andy No, that's not true. I've reduced your question to two simpler exercises: (1) For any $n$, there is a $\Sigma^0_{n+1}$ set which is not $\Sigma^0_n$, and which is contained in $(n, n+1)$. (Actually, the second part follows pretty immediately from the first - just scale the real line!) (2) $\Sigma^0_n$ intersect open is $\Sigma^0_n$. I'm not really sure what your objection is re: countable vs. finite; are you asking why this same argument doesn't also show that you need uncountably many steps to build some Borel sets? (If so, it doesn't - the obstacle is **cofinality**.)

Comment: If you ask a concrete question about my answer, I can address it better. Are either of the exercises particularly unclear? Do you see how - once you've proved the results in the exercises - the $Y$ I've defined is a Borel set which is *not* constructed in finitely many steps, thus answering your question?

Comment: I don't agree. Here's a very simple proof of my question using your exercise: Assume that you could get the borel using n times our functions (at total n, at whatever order), than it is contained in sigma 0 2n, but using the exercise there is a set in sigma 0 2n+1 (which in particular is borel) but not in sigma 0 2n.

Your answer gives a set which is not in any finite steps, which is interesting, but it uses my question which is that finitely many steps isn't everything.

Comment: @Andy Ah, I see - the quantifiers in your question were unclear (I thought you were asking "Can every *individual* Borel set be constructed in finitely many steps?" - I parsed "the Borel set" as "an arbitrary Borel set," not "the class of Borel sets"). You are right, what I wrote previously doesn't address that; I've added a bit of a summary explaining why the Borel hierarchy doesn't collapse after finitely many levels.

Comment: Thanks, although I don't really understand the terms, and it seems pretty difficult (not an execrise I could have completed probably haha). I'll accept the answer, although I'd be much happier if you are aware of an elementary argument.