# Is $S_2$ a sigma algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

In this discussion [$\sigma$ -algebra is the smallest collection of sets which...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/920919/sigma-algebra-is-the-smallest-collection-of-sets-which)

Dave asks whenever $S_2$ is an algebra, but later he observes that  “It would be if we only took finite unions and intersections”, which I don’t really understand.

Could you provide me an example why it is not a sigma algebra?

Comment: I don't see why $S_2$ must be closed under complement. But, I don't understand the original accepted answer either.

Comment: Answered, for example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2017078/659499) (keyword: Borel hierarchy).